# Hide my recent activities on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, hide-elements, activity-feed

How to hide my recent activities on the Activity web part on SharePoint?

This is not to show the files I added, edited or viewed to the entire members who can access the SharePoint site.

Comment: Are you talking about "Site activity" web part in SharePoint online?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to hide the specific activities from Site activity web part in SharePoint online.

> This web part automatically shows recent activity on your site, such as files uploaded, edits made, lists and libraries created, and so on.

**Source**: [Use the Site Activity web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-site-activity-web-part-1fa91401-ac36-42b6-beba-bb8469d6cbfa)

---

**Related reference**: [How to hide SharePoint Online activity in home screen?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/how-to-hide-sharepoint-online-activity-in-home/1ab2a702-36bd-4d4c-a5fd-0486dd8a0aba)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to change or specify contents shown in the Site Activity web part for the time being.

There are a few UserVoice posts you can vote for if you have same requests:
[Customizing the site activity web part.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/41968966-customizing-the-site-activity-web-part) / [Control items in the Site activity web part.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/39229729-control-items-in-the-site-activity-web-part)

As a workaround, remove the Site Activity web part and use [Highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) instead.